# OWASP ZAP bruteforce 3 parameters Request from 3 payloads (parallel)

Tags: brute-force, owasp, zap

How I can fuzz a request with 3 parameters (locations) and 3 payloads:

```
request1 => parameter1=payload1.1;
            parameter2=payload2.1;
            parameter3=payload3.1;

request2 => parameter1=payload1.2;
            parameter2=payload2.2;
            parameter3=payload3.2;

request3 => parameter1=payload1.3;
            parameter2=payload2.3;
            parameter3=payload3.3;
```

Where payload1.2 means take string number 2 from payload1 ... etc.